# How does Asynchronous Server increase throughput by releasing initial I/O thread ?

Tags: java, asynchronous, jersey

In [11.1. Asynchronous Server API](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html) of jersey documentation I could not understand how releasing the thread increases throughput

> It will however increase the throughput of the server, by releasing
>   the initial request processing thread back to the I/O container while
>   the request may still be waiting in a queue for processing or the
>   processing may still be running on another dedicated thread. The
>   released I/O container thread can be used to accept and process new
>   incoming request connections.

And maybe before answering the question other base questions needs to be answered

What is the I/O container, is it the web container ? 
"While the request may still be waiting in a queue" what queue ? If the request is received doesn't this mean that it is been processed ?

Answer (score 1):

Jersey does not necessarily need servlet container, it works with [grizzly](https://grizzly.java.net/) as well. I believe that's why they choose to refer to IO container rather then web or servlet container in the documentation.

The asynchronous requests are handled in parallel, but the server does not have unlimited number of threads or other resources to do so, hence leaving some requests in a queue until the resources are available.

The throughput is increased, since the jersey server does not need to wait until the long running operation is finished, and can return the control to the IO container immediately, allowing container's request processing thread for serving other requests. See nice [article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077995/java-concurrency/java-concurrency-asynchronous-processing-support-in-servlet-3-0.html) about threads and requests and asynchronous processing for details.